# добавить ранее выбранный файл в FileList

Tags: javascript

**Ситуация** инпут типа файл выбирает файл который потом сохраняется в массиве, после этого можно опять воспользоваться этим инпутом для выбора файла. В конце при отправке всех данных на сервер хочу что бы добавленные в массив файлы вставлялись в filelist инпута формы и отправлялись на сервер, **но проблема в том**, что файлы не хотят добавляться методами массива так как filelist  это не массив, не подскажите как добавить ранее выбранные файлы в filelist ?

Comment: Никак. Отправляйте через `FormData`.

Comment: да надо именно через FormData и вообще проблем нет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Что бы отправить файлы на сервер выбранные неоднократным нажатием на один и тот же инпут необходимо аппендить (append) каждый файл в FormData и тогда файлы улетают на сервер без проблем, причём выводятся на серваке в массиве $_FILES, всё как положено